# Finding coordinates of Hexagonal path

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics, linear-algebra, graph-algorithm

I am trying to convert a movement along a straight line ( 2 points) to a movement along Hexagonal path, I tried different formula and did not work.

[image]

I would like to find out the coordinates of P,Q,R,M based on A and B.
I hope someone suggest a better formula which gives me the coordinates  to move a long Hexagonal path.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand what you trying to accomplish, but it would really help (perhaps yourself) if you draw a picture and explain the problem here by making use of that.

Comment: You have no links to the unnamed source where you got "this formula", so large parts of your question are incoherent.  But, rather than just adding a link, you should probably add a readable explanation to the question itself.

Comment: I attached an image to be clearer.

Comment: So you try to find the coordinates of P, Q, R, M as a function of Ax, Ay, Bx, By? I suppose the hexagon is regular (all the internal angles equal to 120 deg.), right? Otherwise you should know the internal angles.

Comment: Draw lines from A to B, P to R and Q to M and find the edge L as a function of Ax and Bx by simple trigonometry. Use sin(30) and cos(30)

Comment: Are you comfortable with vectors?

Comment: ...Or better still, are you comfortable with complex numbers?

Comment: @beta
Thanks for ur reply.
So D will be D= Bx-Ax + By-Ay ??
and what is i ?? what does it mean??

Answer (score 5):

If you are familiar with complex numbers (and assuming this is a regular hexagon),

```
D = B - A
P = A + D( 1 + sqrt(3)i )/4
Q = A + D( 3 + sqrt(3)i )/4
R = A + D( 1 - sqrt(3)i )/4
M = A + D( 3 - sqrt(3)i )/4
```

**EDIT:**

If you are *not* familiar with complex numbers, we should not attempt to use them here. They are a wonderful tool, but not easy to grasp at first. Let's do it the long way:

A = (A<sub>x</sub>, A<sub>y</sub>)
B = (B<sub>x</sub>, B<sub>y</sub>)
D = B - A = (D<sub>x</sub>, D<sub>y</sub>) where D<sub>x</sub>=A<sub>x</sub>-B<sub>x</sub> and D<sub>y</sub>=A<sub>y</sub>-B<sub>y</sub>
P = (A<sub>x</sub> + D<sub>x</sub>/4 - sqrt(3)D<sub>y</sub>/4, A<sub>y</sub> + D<sub>y</sub>/4 + sqrt(3)D<sub>x</sub>/4)
Q = (A<sub>x</sub> + 3D<sub>x</sub>/4 - sqrt(3)D<sub>y</sub>/4, A<sub>y</sub> + 3D<sub>y</sub>/4 + sqrt(3)D<sub>x</sub>/4)
R = (A<sub>x</sub> + D<sub>x</sub>/4 + sqrt(3)D<sub>y</sub>/4, A<sub>y</sub> + D<sub>y</sub>/4 - sqrt(3)D<sub>x</sub>/4)
M = (A<sub>x</sub> + 3D<sub>x</sub>/4 + sqrt(3)D<sub>y</sub>/4, A<sub>y</sub> + 3D<sub>y</sub>/4 - sqrt(3)D<sub>x</sub>/4)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. So D will be D= Bx-Ax + By-Ay ?? and what is i ?? what does it mean??

Answer (score 0):

This is easier to conceptualize if you imagine your hexagon as being made up of vectors - lines with a magnitude (distance) and a direction (angle from the west-to-east horizon rotating counterclockwise).

Call the vector from A to B D. If you use some trigonometry to figure out the geometry of a hexagon, D's magnitude is two times the length of the side of the hexagon. So, we can use this to construct vectors that are as large as our other hexagon sides, and thereby get the hexagon's other points.

Take the vector D, halve its magnitude, rotate it 60 degrees ccw and add this new vector to A's position. This gives you P.

Do the same thing but rotate it 60 degrees cw and add this to A's position. This gives you R.

Similarly, Q is the vector D halved, rotated 60 degrees cw, inverted and added to B's position.

Finally, M is the vector D halved, rotated 60 degrees ccw, inverted and added to B's position.

(To convert a vector into x distance moved and y distance moved, multiply the magnitude by the cos of the angle and by the sin of the angle respectively. Make sure you are using radians if radians are needed and degrees if degrees are needed.)